# how to access a single value from a key that has multiple values in it using dictionary in python

Tags: python

I am quite new to python and was trying to do a question in dictionaries but I am stuck at this one.

Q.Dictionary Coding
Description
Write code to fetch the profession of the employee with Employee id - 104 from an employee input given in the form of a dictionary where key represent employ id and values represent the name, age, and profession (in the same order).

Sample input:

```py
Employee_data = { 101:['Shiva', 24, 'Content Strategist'] ,102:['Udit',25,'Content Strategist'], 103:['Sonam', 28,'Sr Manager'], 104:['Ansari',29,'Product Lead' ],105:['Huzefa',32,'Project Manager' ]}
```

Sample output:

```
'Product Lead'
```

Comment: print(Employee_data[104][2])

Comment: You should definitely have a look at your study material or a tutorial, like the official one: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 1):

Please try beow code:

```
import ast,sys
input_str = sys.stdin.read()
input_dict = ast.literal_eval(input_str)

Employee_list = list( input_dict[104])

profession = Employee_list[2]


print(profession)
```

Answer (score 0):

However in my IDLE environment it is working as expected whereas while implementing the same in the above code I am not getting the proper output.

My code:

```
input_str = '101'
input_dict = {101:['Shiva', 24, 'Content Strategist'] ,102:['Udit',25,'Content Strategist'], 103:['Sonam', 28,'Sr Manager']}
profession=input_dict[int(input_str)][2]
print(profession)
```

But in the above portal I could not give the `profession=input_dict[int(input_string)][2]`.

Comment: This is not very useful in solving the problem.  Also, adding code formatting would help if you wish to enhance the post

Answer (score 0):

```
def getProfession(id):
    return Employee_data[id][2] # second element is the profession

print(getProfession(104)) # Returns "Product Lead"
```

Here is a function I created which when called with the id in its parameters it returns the employees Professions. Python (in my opinion) is a great programming language to index from a list or else as you only have to include an `[index]` to return the needed element.

Answer (score 0):

```
profession = input_dict[104]

print(profession[2])
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide more details e. g. how you came up with the solution, what steps you took, etc. *(A picture does not always answer the question)*

Comment: I was doing the experience and keeping the question I'm mind I tried to solve it as simple as possible. So I selected the variable by key and acceesd it thorough index

Answer (score 0):

For the above question on `Employee_data` of extracting profession I can do this this way right

```py
print (Employee_data[104][2])
```

product lead   #givees answers as

Answer (score -1):

I tried out with this in the beginning: Employee_data[104][2]
but that gave a traceback for Employee_data not being defined.

then however with a little more thought, I was able to work out the solution and it worked out completely with all the test cases passing.

**solution:**

```
import ast,sys
input_str = sys.stdin.read()
input_dict = ast.literal_eval(input_str)

profession=input_dict[104][2]

print(profession)
```

Answer (score -1):

import ast,sys

input_str = sys.stdin.read()

input_dict = ast.literal_eval(input_str)

Employee_list = list( input_dict[104])

profession = Employee_list[2]

print(profession)